# UNION and BETWEEN dates

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, people and shifts and for every person I want to 
get all shifts for a week.
The problem is that there doesn't have to be a shift for every date.
In case there is no shift I want to get a dynamic template result with the date where no shift is availabe

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, s.date_of_shift
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT sh.id, sh.date_of_shift, sh.person_id
    FROM shifts as sh
) AS s ON p.id = s.person_id
WHERE p.id = 2 AND s.date_of_shift BETWEEN '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-25'
UNION ALL
SELECT null, null, '2016-03-21'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM people AS p
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT sh.id, sh.date_of_shift, sh.person_id
        FROM shifts AS sh
    ) AS s ON p.id = s.person_id
    WHERE p.id = 88000 AND s.date_of_shift BETWEEN  '2016-03-21' AND '2016-03-25');
```

This is the query I managed to create. The problem is that I always get the same date. But I want the date in the between range where no shift is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this where you want all dates in a range, even when there is possibly no data for a specific date, you should use the [`generate_series()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) and `LEFT JOIN` your data to it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.name, date_of_shift
FROM generate_series('2016-03-21'::date, '2016-03-25', interval '1 day') AS d(date_of_shift)
LEFT JOIN shifts sh USING (date_of_shift)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, name FROM person WHERE id = 2) p ON p.id = sh.person_id;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c04ae/14)**

Comment: hi patrick, thank you for your answer. unfortunaltely it doesn't quite solve the problem. I made a fiddle to demonstrate that I don't get any result for the days where no shift exists. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c04ae/3/0.

Comment: the problem is definately the where clause [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f2fb7/1) gives something more like what I am looking for. but it didn't specify the person_id. so I need to find a solution for that. I already have an idea but I will work on it tomorrow. thank you for your help. @Patrick

Comment: Hi Elux91. Move the `WHERE` clause into a sub-select and select `DISTINCT` values. See updated answer. Providing a SQLFiddle in the first place - or at the very least table definitions, sample data and expected output - would have given you a suitable answer a few hours ago {;-)

Comment: yea my question was very lackluster. I was in a a bit of a hurry. I'm very thankful that you took the time to answer the question anyway. Using a subselect was what I had in mind. My sample data was a bit crappy (3 shifts for 1 day) so I can drop the DISTINCT. thank you very much.